# Is there a way to enable XML/JSON parsing in Rails 3 only on specific routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, json, security

Given the current Rails security alerts going around, I'm looking at securing applications for a few apps.  Most of them barely make use of the XML/JSON parsing and when they do it's to integrate specific pages or hooks with a 3rd party service.

I've seen the ability to delete default parsers to turn the functionality off completely, but is there a way to enable it / whitelist it on specific routes that may be protected by http basic auth or some other means?  That would at least require somebody attempting to exploit these types of vulnerabilities to know the specific locations where it's enabled.

Comment: So you're saying you want potential vulnerabilities exposed only on some interfaces? That doesn't sound like being more secure.

Comment: Fair point.  The idea was just to leave that functionality enabled at the specific, privately known routes that depended on it rather than simply exposing it application wide.  That would allow for at least reducing the exposure while we worked on the permanent fix.  Transitional code basically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary risk of the current  XML/YAML parse vulnerability has to do with the callbacks that give you richer re-serialization for objects. So one possible way to do this is to just use the lower level APIs that give you parse trees for the XML/YAML, but don't do any hydration beyond Ruby scalars (strings, numbers, hashes, etc). If that doesn't work for you, using a parser like [Yajl](http://lloyd.github.com/yajl/) or, in many cases, just upgrading to the latest versions of the gems, is sufficient to allow parsing to remain on.

Also, the primary risk of the parsing is in the parameter parsing, not response parsing. Response parsing (especially if you can trust the service, and communicate via a secure channel), is a much lower risk since you can control when and where it happens.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're talking about is implemented as Rack middleware, which processes the incoming request before it gets to your controllers.

This middleware is what acts on the list of parsers enabled for different mime types.  You can patch this behavior by re-opening it if you want to add custom rules for when different parameter parsing logic is used on a given request.

[Here's a link to the source.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb)